# GridView on Yii2: How to freeze header (i.e., have a fixed header row)

Tags: php, gridview, yii, yii2

Is there a way to fix GridView header rows in Yii2?

Pretty new to Yii2 and GridView and have made some searches but there seems to be no straightforward answer.

JSFiddle has the full code I'm working on: https://jsfiddle.net/farablanco/cf0zs4uc/

```
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'rowOptions' => function($model){
        },
        'columns' => [
            // 'slug',
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            ['attribute' => 'title',
             'format'=>'raw',
             'value' => function($data){
                return
                Html::a($data->title, '/stock-page/?slugparam=' . $data->slug, ['class'=>'title-link', 'target'=>'_blank']);
             },
             'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'title'],
             ],
            ['attribute' => 'gpa',
             'label' =>'GPA',
             'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'gpa'],
             ],
            ['attribute' => 'dividend_yield',
             'label' =>'Dividend Yield',
             'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'dividend_yield'],
             ],
           ...
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

Comment: what is the fiddle for its of no use? please describe your question properly what you are trying to achieve and what you have done so far

Comment: the jsfiddle don't work properly ... anyway  .. you are looking for a a gridview with blocked/fixed  title of the columns and scrollable rows??  for this could be there are some extensions  .. take a looka in yii site for gridview extensions

Comment: https://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/fixed%20table%20header/ and better https://github.com/bluezed/yii2-floatThead

Answer (score 1):

you can use this extension http://demos.krajee.com/grid,
its a great extension with lots of options,simple to use just add
        'floatHeader'=>false i.e

```
echo GridView::widget([
'dataProvider'=> $dataProvider,
'filterModel' => $searchModel,
'floatHeader'=>false,
'floatHeaderOptions'=>['scrollingTop'=>'50'] ......
```